# Unable to cast object of type 'system.byte ' to type 'system.iconvertible'

Tags: c#, casting

I always gets the error

> unable to cast object of type 'system.byte ' to type 'system.iconvertible"

with my code of retrieving image form DB to a picturebox through a 'SelectedIndexChanged' event of a listview.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem LVI in lvwInventory.SelectedItems)
{
    ////CONNECTION STRING TO THE DATABASE (USED FOR SAVING/UPLOADING IMAGE)
    //System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=..\\dbMyDVDOrganizer.mdb");
    con.Open();
    //OLEDB COMMAND FOR RETRIEVING IMAGE FROM THE DATABASE
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT DVDImage FROM tblDVDInventory WHERE ItemCode='" + lvwInventory.SelectedItems[0].Text + "'");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Byte bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
    MemoryStream memoryBits = new MemoryStream(bits);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryBits);
    //BITMAP HAS THE IMAGE NOW.
    pctImage.Image = bitmap;
}
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: Byte bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);

Comment: I’m quite sure that your bitmap isn’t stored in a single byte…

Comment: An image in a single byte? Are you sure you don't actually want a byte-array? (byte[])

Comment: It says.. 'Parameter is not valid.' when I use byte[].

Comment: Which data type is DVDImage in your database?

Comment: Ole Object in MS Access Database

Answer (score 4):

Just a wild guess: I'd image `DVDImage` contains more than just a `Byte`... maybe a byte array (`Byte[]`)? Replace

```
Byte bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

with

```
Byte[] bits = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<Byte[]>("DVDImage");
```

(or

```
Byte[] bits = (byte[])(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

if you are using an old version of the .NET framework).

Comment: Parameter is not valid. it says.. :(

Comment: This is exactly what I would have said.

Comment: @JamesAndrewCruz Make sure whatever you are passing in is a type accepted by the convert.tobyte method, the list is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobyte.aspx

Comment: This is C#, not VB. I think you got the syntax for `Field()` wrong. It should be `Field<Byte[]>("DVDImage")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Byte bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

with

```
Byte[] bits = (Byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
```

Comment: 'Parameter is not valid' it says... :(

Comment: On which line does it say that?

Comment: Parameter is not valid ont his line: Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryBits);

Comment: @JamesAndrewCruz: That's a different problem with a different cause. You might want to start a new question on that.

Comment: @Heinzi: Funny thing is, he actually did, and it got closed as a duplicate.